# PHP XML foreach

Tags: php, xml, foreach

XML and foreach question

the Title is not issued with unfortunately why? where did I fail can someone help me?

```
foreach ($xml->data->SONGHISTORY->SONG as $dj) {
     echo $dj->PLAYEDAT;
     echo $dj->TITLE;
 }
```

Comment: Could you please clarify the question? What do you see from your `foreach` loop? You should see something like `1392152578Djerem & Shana P - Back To You (T-M-S Remix)1392152331Devel in the Mix by ...`

Comment: Wrap your dump in pre tags so you can actually see the levels of the array

Comment: Any chance you can provide an example of the XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, it seems simply that there is no `data` node in the XML. From your `var_dump` output, you should be using this...

```
foreach ($xml->SONGHISTORY->SONG as $dj) {
    echo $dj->PLAYEDAT, ' ', $dj->TITLE, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Yep, I was about to point out that he was using data in his foreach but not up above under his var_dump

Comment: Yep, remember: _"Don't mention the root element."_ :)